# Multi-level dropdown with li & ul with PHP array loop with CSS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I would like to make a multi level dropdown using li & ul in order to display all the articles of my blog sorted by year and month.
I would like my dropdown to look like the Google Blogspot Dropdown:

[image]

Here are my CSS & HTML codes

```css
ul li {
  list-style: square;
}

ul li ul li {
  list-style: disc;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

ul li ul li ul li {
  list-style: circle;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>2014
    <ul>
      <li>11
        <ul>
          <li>Manifestations en Roumanie</li>
          <li>Article 1</li>
          <li>Article 2</li>
          <li>Article 3</li>
          <li>Article 4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>12
        <ul>
          <li>Article 5</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2015
    <ul>
      <li>10
        <ul>
          <li>Article 6</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2017
    <ul>
      <li>03
        <ul>
          <li>Article 7</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It could look easy at first sight, but the problem is that I have a **PHP array** to display my articles.
Here is my PHP code :

```
$result = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY yr ASC, mo ASC LIMIT 10');

$arr_liste = array();
while($rows = $result->fetch()){
$annee = $rows['yr'];
$mo = $rows['mo'];
$titre = $rows['titre'];
$arr_liste[$annee][$mo][]=$titre; 
}
$result->closeCursor();


echo "<ul>";
foreach($arr_liste as $A=>$M){
echo "<li>" . $A;
echo "<ul>";
foreach($M as $Mkey=>$T){
echo "<li>";
switch($Mkey){
    case '01':
    echo 'Janvier';
    break;
    case '02':
    echo 'Février';
    break;
    case '03':
    echo 'Mars';
    break;
    case '04':
    echo 'Avril';
    break;
    case '05':
    echo 'Mai';
    break;
    case '06':
    echo 'Juin';
    break;
    case '07':
    echo 'Juillet';
    break;
    case '08':
    echo 'Août';
    break;
    case '09':
    echo 'Septembre';
    break;
    case '10':
    echo 'Octobre';
    break;
    case '11':
    echo 'Novembre';
    break;
    case '12':
    echo 'Décembre';
    break;
}
echo "<ul>";
foreach($T as $Titre){
  echo "<li>";
  echo '<a href="#" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">';
  echo $Titre;
  echo "</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Do you have any idea about how I could do that ? I have seen some solutions but they don't work with my PHP code so I gave up.
Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: I don't see any effort here in attempting a dropdown in your CSS. You've only change the list style.

Comment: The truth is that I'm completely lost, I absolutely don't know how to start

Comment: you need to involve something like `display: block` and `display: hidden` somehow in your css.

Comment: but I'm voting to close as too broad. I think that hint should help though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show and hide a list, you need to use a relative selector ocmbined with stopPropagation (so it doesn't hide based on the top most li you click on).

```js
$("li").click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).find("ul").toggle();
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: square;
}

ul li ul li {
  list-style: disc;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

ul li ul li ul li {
  list-style: circle;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>2014
    <ul>
      <li>11
        <ul>
          <li>Manifestations en Roumanie</li>
          <li>Article 1</li>
          <li>Article 2</li>
          <li>Article 3</li>
          <li>Article 4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>12
        <ul>
          <li>Article 5</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2015
    <ul>
      <li>10
        <ul>
          <li>Article 6</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2017
    <ul>
      <li>03
        <ul>
          <li>Article 7</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```